# How to send an Email with longitude and latitude coordinates or maybe send a Google static map using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to send an Email with longitude and latitude coordinates or maybe send a Google static map using c#. The information should represent the sender email address or IP address as to where the sender is located.

I am using a simple email form and would like to add this feature to it. How do I go about this ? I am open to any suggestions or different ways of achieving this.

Comment: Do you want a database of IP addresses tagged to lat/long co-ordinates?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Javascript Geolocation API. See [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2023-Geocoding-A-User-s-Location-Using-Javascript-s-GeoLocation-API.htm). For the map you'll send the lat & long to Google Maps. See [this](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=18539). Once you do the map search, just use the link button to get the URL. It then shouldn't be hard to reverse engineer the URL to apply it to a more general case.

To do the static image, as per @Haedrian, use [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/imageapis/index.html). You can also wrap that with a link to the URL as described above.

Comment: To add to this: https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/imageapis/index.html - You can very easily put in an image without needing to 'reverse engineer' the url